# Pig : Use to Write record types in a single file to multiple outputs

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have the following data in a single file

```
"HD",003498,"20160913:17:04:10","D3ZYE",1
"EH","XXX-1985977-1",1,"01","20151215","20151215","20151229","20151215","2304",,,"36-126481000",1340.74,61808.00,1126.62,0.00,214.12,0.00,0.00,0.00,"30","20151229","00653845",,,"PARTS","001","ABI","20151215","Y","Y","N","36-126481000",
```

I would like to use Pig to read this single file and then segregate it to different files based on the first column 
In the same light, I was looking for a way to treat the record first as a following construct:

recTypCd, recordData

And then later on just treat recordData as a CSV record

In this regard, after I store them in separate files with the same record types, I can simply load them to its own External HIVE Tables by using a CSV serde

Comment: Already gave you an Hive solution.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, this exercise is to allow the spltting of the files into multiple files first before defining the HIVE construct.. i was looking for ways to supply a filter criteria to PIG to output (or DUMP) only the records for each record type in several distinct outputs

Answer (score 0):

You can use split by in pig based on your condition

E.g multiple =split line by recTypeCd
Case hd1 when rectypecd ==‘hd’,
Case hd2 ...

Store hd1 into op1;
Store hd2 into op2;